# What features or concepts annoy you in Qt?

Tags: qt, qt4

[Qt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qt_(framework)) is a nice framework and great UI toolkit and it has [many useful features and concepts](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/classes.html). Most of us probably agree that [Trolltech](http://qt.nokia.com/), lately [Nokia](http://www.nokia.com/), have done pretty nice job developing it. One of the latest advances in Qt is [QML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QML), which I find fascinating advancement.

However, I find some of the concepts badly designed or badly implemented, such as [Model/View](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/model-view-programming.html) (the concept is fine, but implementation is not) and same goes for [Phonon](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/phonon-module.html) media framework. Some people say its the [meta-object](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/moc.html) concept that drives them crazy.

All of this are obviously more or less subjective, but **what features or concepts do you find annoying or burdensome to use in Qt** and how do you circumvent around them?

Comment: It almost looks like people like Qt too much to critize it :-)

Comment: I'll put up an another +50 bounty to get more great answers! Keep em coming.

Comment: This should at the very least be community wiki

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Most of my gripes with Qt come from the fact that the API does not fully embrace the dynamism provided by QObject. If you dared to create a meta-object compiler to add dynamic behavior to C++, why be shy about it, then?

All the stuff I list below are things my team needed at some point and we had to code it ourselves. It was a lot of fun and we learned a lot about the Qt internals, but I wouldn't mind if it was already done and ready to use.

**No Distributed QObject**

You know, like in Cocoa. They went half way with QtDBus -- the only thing left to do is the networking. We had to implement our own solution for this, and since we live outside the Qt code, we cannot change internals to implement all nice features.

**No API for data storage**

And of course everyone writes their own incomplete QObject-to-SQLite library. QDataStream is a very good beginning, though.

**No Data Binding**

Well, Qt Quick has data binding, but data binding should live in QtCore. With decent data binding, writing QAbstractItemModels that represent collections of QObjects should be a thing of the past: QObjectListModel should be all you need.

(Yeah, QDataWidgetMapper is a joke.)

**No Automatic Undo Management for QObjects**

Our model classes are usually QObjects and Q_PROPERTY has an optional NOTIFY signal that is exactly what is needed to implement automatic undo. It's so easy to do it should already be part of Qt. (It requires a few kludges, however.)

**No Collection Properties**

Not all properties are born equal. Some of them are collections. Being able to deal with those in an abstract way would be definitely a good thing.

**Half-baked QMetaStuff API**

And I only hate this API because I love it. For instance, one cannot:

1. build QMetaObjects dynamically and replace them;
2. call a meta-method using a QVariants as arguments;
3. query methods by return type, name, or argument types;
4. connect signals and slots using the respective QMetaMethods ([at least not until 4.8](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-10637));
5. intercept property set/get in the same way you can intercept events, for instance.

Almost all of those can be worked around easily. A solution for #2:

```
QVariant call(QObject* object, QMetaMethod metaMethod, QVariantList args)
{
    QList<QGenericArgument> arguments;

    for (int i = 0; i < args.size(); i++) {

        // Notice that we have to take a reference to the argument. A 
        // const_cast is needed because calling data() would detach 
        // the QVariant.

        QVariant& argument = args[i];

        QGenericArgument genericArgument(
            QMetaType::typeName(argument.userType()),
            const_cast<void*>(argument.constData())
        );

        arguments << genericArgument;
    }

    QVariant returnValue(QMetaType::type(metaMethod.typeName()), 
        static_cast<void*>(NULL));

    QGenericReturnArgument returnArgument(
        metaMethod.typeName(),
        const_cast<void*>(returnValue.constData())
    );

    // Perform the call

    bool ok = metaMethod.invoke(
        object,
        Qt::AutoConnection, // In case the object is in another thread.
        returnArgument,
        arguments.value(0),
        arguments.value(1),
        arguments.value(2),
        arguments.value(3),
        arguments.value(4),
        arguments.value(5),
        arguments.value(6),
        arguments.value(7),
        arguments.value(8),
        arguments.value(9)
    );

    if (!ok) {
        // Handle the error...
    } else {
        return returnValue;
    }
}
```

**Useful features will probably be removed**

There is talk in qt-interest that the [DOM](http://lists.qt.nokia.com/pipermail/qt-interest/2010-March/021020.html), [style sheets](http://lists.qt.nokia.com/pipermail/qt-interest/2010-June/024940.html), and [custom file engines](http://lists.qt.nokia.com/pipermail/qt-interest/2010-July/025317.html) will be removed in a future version of Qt.

**Phonon has no cross-platform back-end**

Besides not really working all the time, Phonon has no stable back-end that works on the three most common platforms: Windows, Linux and Mac OS X. There is a VLC back-end, but it's definitely not stable, its licensing is unclear and, moreover, VLC support for Mac is "[resting on shaky ground](http://theappleblog.com/2009/12/18/vlc-for-mac-resting-on-shaky-ground/)". The blame is entirely on Linux, of course. Multimedia support has [never been](http://tuxradar.com/content/how-it-works-linux-audio-explained) [one of its strengths](http://braid-game.com/news/?p=364). It lacks something like Quicktime or the DirectStuff.

**No Crypto Classes**

There is QCryptographicHash and QSSLSocket (and its [funny error modes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3435024/qt-qsslerror-being-signaled-with-the-error-code-set-to-noerror/3436700#3436700)), and that's it. Fortunately, there are two good libraries to fill this gap: [Botan](http://botan.randombit.net/) and [QCA](http://delta.affinix.com/qca/). QCA is based on Qt, but copies its API from the Java crypto classes so, not very good. Botan has a nifty interface and (but?) is "pure" C++. A Qt-style crypto library is still lacking.

Comment: +1: Thorough answer that reveals your deep knowledge of Qt.

Comment: +1 for QMetaMethod invoke using QVariants. Is it possible to provide wrongly typed parameters which can be implicitly casted to the correct type? Let's say I want to call `foo(long)`, is it possible to call your solution with a `QVariant::Int`? I need this in my app and am currently using a really dirty hacked alternative solution which I want to get rid of.

Comment: @leemes: As it is, no. But I think it can be done. You must compare the types of the supplied `args` list with the metamethod `parameterTypes` and attempt to create a type-compatible list using `QVariant::canConvert` and `QVariant::convert`. If you can't convert the list, the call fails. I'll try it here and report if it works.

Comment: @andref Thank you. If you want to take a look at my code: https://bitbucket.org/leemes/qtsimplerpc/src/ed92604fd7ba/qtsimplerpc/rpccommandmapper.cpp#cl-390 Here I use a custom type converter and use Qt meta call to do call the method.

Comment: @leemes I wrote a quick hack that seems to work (I tested it, but not exhaustively): https://gist.github.com/2838534

Comment: @leemes If the conversions supplied by `QVariant` are enough for you, my code may help. However, you'd have to register every specialization of the complex types you use (such as `QMap<QString, QMap<QString, T>>`) using `qRegisterMetaType` on both the client and the server sides.

Comment: @andref Thanks four your gist. There seem to be two solutions to the problem, both having their own drawback. Your gist is restricted to types known by the Qt meta system, mine is restricted to a limited depth of nested lists and maps and a few "inner" types. But I think, both solutions are flexible enough to handle the most common types; yours is even better because the user can register his own types and they are compatible with the meta call. So thank you very much for this alternative solution. I might replace it in my project! Cheers

Comment: I noticed that your solution is restricted to 10 arguments. But you could just use qt_metacall (which isn't documented, but the usage isn't that much different to QMetaMethod::invoke). It also needs the argument as `void*` with the correct types behind the pointer. I will combine both our codes to a solution which handles all meta types + my limited nested lists and maps of some primitive types. I drop a comment when I'm done.

Comment: @andref I updated my code to support all meta types known by Qt at runtime using `QVariant::create()` and `QVariant::destruct()` **and** my old method supporting a limited depth of nested types (`QList<T>` and `QMap<QString,T>`) with a limited count of inner types `T`. See my updated code at https://bitbucket.org/leemes/qtsimplerpc/src/4889425039bd/qtsimplerpc/rpccommandmapper.cpp#cl-206 Thank you again for your help!

Answer (score 11):

This is an odd question for SO to sanction, but here goes:

`qmake` is long in the tooth (and I'm [not the only one to say so](http://labs.trolltech.com/blogs/2009/10/14/to-make-or-not-to-make-qmake-and-beyond-redux/)).  I use `cmake`, despite it having its own awkwardness.

The meta-object preprocessing build step for signals/slots/etc. is a huge buy-in.  And many who'd be willing to accept the added level of abstraction are the sorts of people who'd be attracted to other environments (Java, C#, whatever-the-hey).  On the other side of the fence are the hardcore C++ programmers who would rather work with `std::thread` instead of `QThread`.

*(If a C++ program is more server-oriented and has no GUI, people seem to avoid Qt, and I see their point.)*

The model/view is neither here nor there, but it's kind of trivial.  I've criticized issues of thread affinity:

http://blog.hostilefork.com/qt-model-view-different-threads/

Also, I've cross-compiled apps to Mac and Windows and Linux, and found Qt doesn't protect me from platform issues as much I might've wished.  If you look at the internals and how drag and drop is implemented by extremely diverse code *(e.g. `qnd_x11.cpp`, `qdnd_win.cpp`, and `qdnd_mac.mm`)* then you see that the ["Leaky Abstraction"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaky_abstraction) principle comes into play.  Qt doesn't impose strong formalisms; you get the messages you get in varying order, or in duplicates--or not at all on some platforms.

But all criticisms aside, I do like Qt's design, documentation, community support, and general aesthetic.  You could do a lot worse!  *(I'm looking at you, wxWidgets and GTK.)*

Comment: You sometimes find valuable information this way: people hate/are annoyed by something and they circumvent it by doing the same thing in another, possibly better possibly worse, way. I also like Qt, so this isn't bashy question :)

Answer (score 5):

The problem I tried to solve is general for Qt, wxWidgets and possibly other UI frameworks:

```
void MainDialog::OnCppException()
{
    throw std::runtime_error("test unhandled exception");
}
```

Such unhandled C++ exception is caught by Qt framework, preventing immediate exception debugging or generating informative crash dump. In the place where Qt allows to handle this situation, original exception information and stack trace are lost. I tried to fight with this problem in both frameworks, and didn't find acceptable solution. The advice from Qt professionals "Just don't do this" is all I have, this actually means: don't make bugs, and everything will be OK. This was my greatest disappointment from Qt and wxWidjets.

Answer (score 1):

I'm working mostly on Qt for S60 environment, so some of the issues are specific for that platform.

**Plugin system + QObjects**

You cannot declare plugin interface with signals, because the plugin implementations are supposed to derive from QObject and multiple interfaces, so the interface shouldn't be QObject itself (required if you want some signals in your interface). The workaround I found on Qt-interest mailing list is adding a MyQObject* getter to your plugin interface and adding all signals to concrete MyQObject class. It works, but it's counterintuitive and ugly.

**QSet and other Qt containers are less versatile than stl or boost containers**

For example you can't define less function that should be used when inserting elements into QSet. Other stuff I miss is remove_if and find_if.

**QServiceFramework in QtMobility package**

Ridiculous library I was recently forced to use. To use a "service" installed in QServiceFramework you either have to link to dll which contains that service (which is quite pointless, considering that one of the QSf goals is to hide dependencies) or use QMetaObject::invokeMethod that doesn't provide compile-time checking of methods, argument types, etc. and reduces code readability:

```
// using QMetaObject::invokeMethod
QVariantHash data;
bool ok = QMetaObject::invokeMethod(myObject, "getStuff", 
    Q_RETURN_ARG(QVariantHash, data)
    Q_ARG(QString, QString("blah")));
Q_ASSERT(ok);

// using normal syntax
QVariantHash data(myObject->getStuff("blah"));
```

To make things worse, it uses file system quite a lot (iterating dirs looking for plugins, communication with SQLite database), which is a slow operation on S60.

**QPixmap requires QApplication...**

...and only QPixmap have methods for conversion between native S60 images (CFbsBitmap class) and Qt data. So you either have to make your app an QApplication (which increases startup times and memory consumption) or you have to store the data in native S60 structures (which makes the whole code Symbian specific)

Comment: Most Qt containers are compatible with the STL algorithms, so you can always call remove_if and find_if on them.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know about that. Thanks!

Comment: You can declare pure virtual signals in the plugin interface.

Answer (score 1):

I had same same problem, trying to invoke a method with variant arguments. I reported the issue here: https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-28833

They in fact recommended me to use undocumented implementation details to work around the problem. So I think its worth to link it here.

The issue was finally accepted (priority low and for Qt5 only).